# Meaning of "To blush up to one's ears"

Tags: meaning-in-context

I have Googled 'to blush up to one's ears', but couldn't find its meaning. Here is the context:

> 'Darlin, how I wished you were ten years older!'
>
> 'I will be," Bob said matter-of-fact, even though he had blushed up to his ears. "In ten years."

What does this expression mean here?

Answer (score 4):

> [Blush](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/blush): to become red in the face especially from shame, modesty, or confusion

Blush up to his ears is an exaggeration of the word blush, meaning Bob was very embarrassed to hear someone say that she wishes he was 10 years older.

Answer (score 1):

I [looked it up](http://dictionary.reverso.net/english-cobuild/to%20blush%20right%20up%20to%20the%20ears), and it does mean what the common phrase means. When someone blushes, their face turns red-- usually on the cheeks. The sentence uses the *"up to his cheeks"* portion of the sentence to show that Bob was blushing greatly.

Put simply, Bob was blushing a lot, to the point where the 'redness' reached his ears.